# Cant see error messages on the screen for jquery validation

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

Please help me, I dont know where I am going wrong.
I cant see any error messages when I click on submit.

Here is the code-

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://jakarta.apache.org/struts/tags-html"
    prefix="html"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://jakarta.apache.org/struts/tags-bean"
    prefix="bean"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Login</title>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.jquery.com/view/trunk/plugins/validate/jquery.validate.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).submit(function(){  

    $("#LoginForm").validate({
        errorPlacement: function(error,element){
        return true;
        },
      rules: {      
        "loginName": {
                required: true,
                minlength: 5

            },
        "password":{
                required: true,
                minlength: 5

            }    
      },

      messages:{
          "loginName":{
                              required:"Email must be supplied",
                              minlength:"specify at least 5 characters"

          },
          "password":{
              required:"Email must be supplied",
              minlength:"specify at least 5 characters"

            }

       }

    });  
  });

   </script>


</head>
<body>
<form id="LoginForm" name="LoginForm"
  action="SignIn.do" method="post"
        enctype="multipart/form-data" >
    <table bordercolor="#FFFF33" border="10" height="100%" width="100%">

    <tr valign="top">
    <td>
        <table align="top">
        <tr>
            <td>User Name</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="loginName" name="loginName" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Password</td>
            <td><input type="password" id="password" name="password" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" />
        </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
    </tr>

    </table>
    </form>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're specifying an `errorPlacement` function, it's up to you to insert the error message in the document.

Your `errorPlacement` function does nothing, so the error message won't be inserted anywhere. You'll need to either remove `errorPlacement` to get the default behavior, or modify it so it inserts its first argument somewhere in the document.

You can find more information about `errorPlacement` and the other validation options [here](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions).

Comment: Its working neither way, if I remove the errorPlacement or modify it. It still doesn't show me anything, and I am using this jsp in struts framework. It works if I run it as a simple html file.